# Value of Regression Coefficient of Conditionally Independet Variable

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Suppose we known that $E[Y\mid X=x]=f(\alpha + x\beta)$ for some pararmetic prediction method $f$. Consider now $E[Y\mid X=x, Z=z]=f(\alpha + x\beta + z\gamma)$. If $Y \perp\!\!\!\perp Z\mid X$ under which conditions will the regression parameter $\gamma$ be zero?

Answer (score 1):

If given $X$; $Y$ and $Z$ are conditionally independent, we'll have $$E[Y|X=x,Z=z]=E[Y|X=x]$$
which will make $\gamma=0$ always.